# When the unit of a universal property is an isomorphism

Tags: category-theory

Let $G \colon \mathbf B \to \mathbf A$ be a functor, and let $A \in \mathbf A$ be an object. A universal arrow from $A$ to $G$ can be described by an isomorphism of functors
\begin{equation}
\mathbf B(X,-) \cong \mathbf A(A, G(-)).
\end{equation}
In fact, by Yoneda lemma, the existence of such isomorphism is equivalent to the existence of a unit map $\eta \colon A \to G(X)$ such that for any map $f \colon A \to G(B)$, there exists $f' \colon  X \to B$ such that
\begin{equation}
f = G(f')\eta.
\end{equation}
Now, if $\eta$ is an isomorphism, then obviously $A \cong G(X)$. Is the converse true? That is, if $A \cong G(X)$, is it true that also $\eta$ is an isomorphism? What one is able to do, given an isomorphism $u \colon A \to G(X)$, is to apply the universal property and find a unique $h \colon X \to X$ such that
\begin{equation}
u = G(h)\eta.
\end{equation}
Is it possible to go on from this point? In the case that $G$ has a global left adjoint $F$, then [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/892767/84624) tells me that actually the unit of the adjunction is an iso, if there exists an isomorphism of functors $1 \cong GF$. Instead, how could we argue in this "local" situation? Or, is there a counterexample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. Here a counterexample.

Consider the forgetful functor 
$$G \colon \mathbf{Ab} \to \mathbf {Set}$$
that sends every abelian group into its underlying set, and let 
$$F \colon \mathbf {Set} \to \mathbf {Ab}$$
be its left adjoint, the free-abelian group functor. For the set $\mathbb Z$, or if you like to be precise $G(\mathbb Z)$, we have that the universal arrow is given by the function 
$$\eta \colon \mathbb Z \to \oplus_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z$$
$$\eta(n)=e_{n}\ ,$$
where $e_n$ is the element having all, but the $n$-th components equal to $0$.

The function $\eta$ isn't an isomorphism, since it isn't surjective, nonetheless both $\mathbb Z$ and $\oplus_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Z$ are countable, hence isomorphic in $\mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: I think, either you work with $\bf Ab$ instead of $\bf Grp$ here, or the $\oplus_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Z$ should be the free group $F_\omega$ on $\omega$ generators. Or, do I miss something?

Comment: @Berci yes you're right :) thanks for pointing out.